# Trivial assignment of int* skipped

Tags: c++, pointers

The following gdb extract should make it clear:

```
Breakpoint 1, stack<int>::top (this=0x603010, head_element=0x7fffffffe560)
    at stack.cpp:47
47              return 1;
(gdb) list 46
41      {
42          if(head==0)
43              return 0;
44          else
45          {
46              head_element=head->element;
47              return 1;
48          }
49      }
50
(gdb) p head_element
$1 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe560
(gdb) p head->element
$2 = (int *) 0x603050
(gdb)
```

Notice that I have a breakpoint at **Line 47**, thus Line 46 should have been executed. But as it is clearly shown, the assignment did not really work out.

I do not understand at all why.

**Edit:**
**stack.cpp**

```
#include "stack.hpp"

template <class T>
stack<T>::stack()
{
    //empty stack
    head=0;
}

template <class T>
stack<T>::stack(const stack<T> &to_copy_to)
{
    head = to_copy_to.head;
}

template <class T>
void stack<T>::operator=(const stack<T> &rhs)
{
    head = rhs.head;
}

template <class T>
stack<T>::~stack()
{
    delete head;
}

template <class T>
void stack<T>::push(T n)
{
    struct stack_node *new_node = new struct stack_node;
    new_node->element = new T;
    *(new_node->element) = n;

    new_node->next=head;
    head = new_node;
}

template <class T>
int stack<T>::top(T* head_element)
{
    if(head==0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        *head_element=*(head->element);
        return 1;
    }
}

template <class T>
void stack<T>::pop()
{
   if(head!=0)
   {
       head=head->next;
   }
}

template <class T>
int stack<T>::size()
{
    int count = 0;
    stack_node* iter=head;
    while(iter!=0)
    {
        count++;
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

**stack.hpp**

```
#ifndef _STACK_HPP_
#define _STACK_HPP_

template<class T>
class stack {
private:
        // Add your member variables here

        //I can't work around without a node structure
        struct stack_node{
                T* element;
                stack_node* next;
        }*head;

public:
        /**
         * Default constructor for the stack class
         */
        stack();

        /**
         * Copy constructor for the stack class.
         * Params:
         * const stack &to_copy_to : A reference to the stack object to be copied
         * into.
         */
        stack(const stack &to_copy_to);

    /*
     * Assignment overload, to fulfill rule of three
     */
    void operator=(const stack &rhs);

        /**
         * Default destructor for the stack class
         */
        ~stack();

        /**
         * Pushes an object of type T on the top of the stack
         * Params:
         * T n : The object to be pushed on the top of the stack
         */
        void push(T n);

        /**
         * Gives the element on the top of the stack, if any
         * Params:
         * T *top_element : Pointer to the location where the top element is to be
         *                  stored before returning
         * Return value:
         * int : Positive if stack is non empty, negative if it is empty
         */
        int top(T *top_element);

        /**
         * Removes the element on the top of the stack, if any
         */
        void pop();

        /**
         * Returns the number of elements in the stack
         * Return value:
         * int : Number of elements in the stack
         */
        int size();
};

#endif //_STACK_HPP_
```

**Edit2:**
Modifying line 46 as

```
*head_element=*(head->element);
```

solves my program, but I am still curious as to wtf is going on.

Comment: Can you post the declaration of `head` and `head_element`?

Comment: @lc. See edit. Added full code

Comment: What are your compile options? Make sure you're compiling with `-O0` when using GDB

Comment: It's possible that, since the assignment had no effect, the compiler optimized it out.

Comment: @gmbeard How does it matter if using GDB or not? I have an erroneous output for testcases even when I compiled without GDB. 
I anyway tried that, no help.

Comment: @Claudiu Wow? :P 
But the assignment had an "effect", what really goes on? Should I invoke objdump and inspect more?

Comment: @Cheeku: Hmm `head_element = head->element` has no effect, because all you're doing is changing a local variable `head_element`, and that variable is never used after that assignment. It's like doing `void foo(int i) { i = 14; }`: that assignment can't possibly affect the program. However, `*head_element = *(head->element)` *does* have an effect, and so it's not optimized out. If you want to do debugging without weird things like this then make sure the optimization level is 0, as @gmbeard said.

Comment: Or declare `head_element` to be `volatile`, so assignments to it are not optimized out.

Comment: @Claudiu I understand that perspective, but but...-O0 doesn't help at all

Comment: @Cheeku @Claudiu has given you the answer; you're passing `head_element` by value. It's a pointer, sure, but it won't preserve its value when the function returns

Comment: Your Edit2 gives a good clue: What's the difference between `*(head)->element` and `*(head->element)`?

Comment: @gmbeard @Claudiu Is `head_element` local when the method is declared as `int stack<T>::top(T* head_element)`? (I.e. pointer to the type)

Comment: @CraigYoung Not really! Even in GDB I was using *(head->element) to take output! That's certainly not the problem. *(head)->element would be illegal nonetheless.

Comment: @CraigYoung, yes. Any assignments to `head_element` will not be preserved after the function returns. @Claudiu, maybe you should write a full answer to explain. This comment thread is already too long

Answer (score 4):

`head_element=head->element;` was optimized out by the compiler because it causes no *observable behaviour*.

You set the value of a local variable `head_element` but then that variable's value is never used before it is destroyed at the end of the function.

Function parameters which were passed by value are the same sort of thing as local variables.

Comment: How do I avoid that? -O0 doesn't help

Comment: You can't. It is part of the language definition of C++.  So long as the executable produces the right output the compiler can use whatever assembly instructions it likes.

Comment: You can try to make head_element volatile but there is no guarantee it will do anything.

Comment: @M.M I also forgot to mention, the line does execute the first 2 times it is called for the specific testcase I am using, but fails the third time.